# How to change a piston direction?

Tags: java, bukkit

I need some help to change a piston direction while placing it programmatically.

I use this method to set my block type to a piston:

```
block.setType(Material.PISTON_BASE);
```

But I can't find a method to change its direction, and point it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bukkit has utility methods to change facing of the piston using the [MaterialData](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/index.html?org/bukkit/material/MaterialData.html) api, this api can be used as follows:

```
Block block = ....;
BlockState state = block.getState();
PistonBaseMaterial piston = (PistonBaseMaterial)state.getData();

piston.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.NORTH);
piston.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.SOUTH);
piston.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.WEST);
piston.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.EAST);
piston.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.UP);
piston.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.DOWN);

state.setData(piston);
state.update();
```

Outside of the direction, we can also power/unpower the piston by calling `piston.setPowered(true/false);`. We can also easily check if the piston is a sticky one by calling the method `piston.isSticky()`, without relying on the other deprecated methods since we are no longer using "magic id's" anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it using method:

```
block.setTypeIdAndData(33, (byte)direction, false);
```

If you would like to place sticky pistons, use `29` for the first parameter.

The direction values are the following:

> 0: Down
>   1: Up
>   2: North
>   3: South
>   4: West
>   5: East

For the last parameter, `false` means disable unneccessary block updates caused by the block placement.